# Check go expression availability at compile time

Tags: go

I am writing a (hobby) compiler for Go.

Now for optimizing I am wondering: Is there a way yet to check whether data inside `ast.Expr` can be accessed at compile time?

I know that I can parse through to `ast.*Lit`.

Comment: As literally nothing can be accessed at compile time you must have something non-obvious in mind. Please explain what you are trying to to and elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Object code is result of compilation process.

> In a general sense object code is a sequence of statements or instructions in a computer language, usually a machine code language (i.e., binary).

Before compilation finished nothing can be accessed.

Comment: While compiling you can access constant object code just fine.